# React no closing end tag

Tags: reactjs

Whats wrong with this piece of code ?

```
import React from "react";

export default function Azubis() {
return ( < div > < /div>)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There should be no spaces between `<` and `/` in closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: Yes, a space after the '<' for the closing div tag throw an error, you can test it on stackblitz easily