# React syntax error, can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Error: JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error

I am a beginner and I am just starting out. I have looked at similar questions being posted here about error in syntax but I am still not able to figure out what the problem is.
Basically,"JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)". I have checked my code but there are all the necessary closing tags. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = "App" >
      
      <h1 > Basic React App < /h1> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After hitting save, this is also coming up with the error "(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>
"

Comment: Is this the whole code or a part of it or a pseudocode? But first, try to remove the spaces around your tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React no closing end tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962589/react-no-closing-end-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the space in closing H1 tag. There should be no whitespace inside.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1> Basic React App </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Please refer to this link in react playground for interactive result
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3kvuo?file=/index.js:0-277

Comment: I get it but whenever I am saving the file, it automatically is providing those extra spaces between the tags. Is there some setting I should do in vscode or what?

Comment: So you might have some sort of linter installed. This could be an eslint file that has a hook or something else that is part of the project. maybe even a plugin in vscode or any other editor that you use.